# Read Project File in QGIS Macro

Tags: pyqgis

One of the things I really like about ArcGIS Pro is that, when you start a new project, it prompts you to create a new .gdb associated with the project. I'm attempting to replicate this behavior in QGIS by having a macro in a project template - when the template is opened, it should prompt the user for a save location and name, and create a new .qgz project/GeoPackage with the selected name.

The problem I'm running into is that, while the macro is correctly creating/saving the new .qgz file, the call to `QgsProject.instance().read(file)` doesn't appear to be persistent. The `print()` statement at the end of the macro returns the name of the .qgz created, but if I open Project -> Properties -> General, "Project file" is blank - the project instance is now blank.

Here's the macro code:

```
from qgis.utils import iface

def openProject():
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    if "emplate" in project.fileName():
        from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
        from qgis.core import (
            QgsProviderRegistry,
            QgsVectorLayer,
            )
        from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
        from shutil import copy

        title = "Save Location (without extension):"
    
        result = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, title, "C:\\Default_Location")
        projname = result[0]
        parts = projname.split("/")
        dbname = parts[-1]

        if dbname:
            file = projname + ".qgz"
            package = projname + ".gpkg"
            project.write(file)
            project.read(file)
            template_db = "C:\\path_to_template\\template.gpkg"
            new_db = projname + ".gpkg"
            copy(template_db, new_db)
            group = "providers/ogr/GPKG/connections"
            s = QSettings()
            s.beginGroup(group)
            s.remove("")
            s.endGroup()
            layer_path = new_db + "|layername=template"
            vl = QgsVectorLayer(layer_path, 'template', 'ogr')
            md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('ogr')
            conn = md.createConnection(vl.dataProvider().dataSourceUri(), {})
            md.saveConnection(conn, dbname)
            iface.reloadConnections()
            
    iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
    print(project.fileName())
```

I've tried calling `project.clear()` between the write and read calls, that didn't work either.

An interesting quirk I've just discovered is that implementing `QgsProject.instance().write(file)` and `QgsProject.instance().read(file)` *in the console* produces the desired behavior. It appears the issue lies in the fact that this is being run as a macro...

Comment: What is supposed to happen with that write and read?

Comment: @bugmenot123 ```QgsProject.instance().write()``` saves the active project - passing it a filename is a "save-as." Since I start this process by opening my template .qgz, the write call saves a copy of the template to the location/name specified. ```QgsProject.instance().read()``` changes the current instance to the file specified as an argument.

Comment: Is the same macro run again on that read call?

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes, but since the whole thing is in an ```if``` block nothing should be getting regenerated as long as I'm naming the new project something other than "template."